# Updating App to Android Marketplace

Tags: android, google-play

This is hopefully a basic question - i'm new to Android dev -  I want to update my android app in marketplace,  its the 2nd ever edition.

So in the Manifest file I've left version code as 1 and made versionName 1.2, is this correct?  Just because the android docs appear to state I should change both?

Cheers
Paul

Comment: Version code should be incremented for every updates. You can leave the Version name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The important part is changing the version code, this is what dictates whether an update is required.

If version 2 exists in the market, and the user has version 1 (or anything lower than 2) installed, they'll be informed that there's an update.

The versionName is purely for display purposes and you can leave it the same, or change it when you make a new release.

Comment: Just to add, though it is not required to update versionName, but is is not less important. Because, if Market says there is an update but I can see that the version is same as before (because user sees the versionName, not versionCode) --- I might not want to update the app.

Comment: cheers for the advice guys, very helpful.   The developer console lists the app as published but it states 'draft app v1.1', why does it say draft!?

Comment: It will be a draft until you activate it.

Answer (score 1):

You have to change versionCode to higher value than in previous publish (in your case 2, if first edition was 1). This value has to be an integer.

As for VersionName is a basic readable string for user it has no meaning for AM service, so you can write here anything you want.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Version code of newer version should be higher. :)